# NiFi - How solve updating file concurrence problem

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to make a flow that takes a file (FetchFile), appends the incoming data  (ReplaceText with Append) and saves this same file (PutFile using replace).

The problem is that sometimes there are arriving more than one flowfile at almost the same time, and it could happen that before the first flowfile has finished (PutFile using replace file), a second flowfile is merging with the file (that it is not already updated with the first flowfile).
The flowfile is the next one:

[image]

How can I control this concurrence proble?

Cheers.

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean, are you saying two flow files arrive at the ReplaceText processor at the same time? If so, it will only processor one of them at a time unless you have changed the Concurrent Tasks setting of the processor to something > 1

Comment: question edited. Not at the same time. The thing is that it can happen that the second flowfile arrives to the replace text, before that the first flowfile has arrived to the putfile, so the information of the file it woudn't be updated.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused because PutFile is writing to an external file that is outside of NiFi's repositories, with ReplaceText it is modifying flow file content that has been brought into NiFi's repositories by FetchFIle, so at the point of ReplaceText it is no longer related to whatever PutFile is writing to

Comment: with the PutFile I am editting the same File (I am replacing the old file)

Comment: So FetchFile is fetching the same file that PutFIle is writing to?

Comment: yes, the file in fetchfile and the putfile are the same

Comment: Ok I think it would be best to avoid fetching and writing to the same file, maybe you can have PutFile write to a temp file somewhere and follow it with another processor like ExecuteStreamCommand that renames the temp file to the final name

Comment: It's now a good practice to read/write in the same folder.